# Application window size limit in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with Windows 10: When I try to resize one of my (non maximized) running applications, I notice that there is a maximum size that cannot be exceeded, both as height and width. It seems to be about the screen size, but not exactly. For example, I cannot resize the Notepad++ window to the screen width: it is about 10 px smaller!

[image: Notepad++ maximum width]

Additionally, it seems every program has a different maximum. Windows Explorer can be resized to the screen width and height and even a bit more.

And here my question: is there a way to disable this maximum window size limit or any workaround? I would prefer not to use a third-party software.

Comment: I would guess this probably has to do with your graphics driver.

Comment: This is unusual... There is not normally a way to set a limit on the application window size in Windows 10. For instance Notepad++ can size to substantially more than the width of a large desktop (~3200 pixels of application window width). Perhaps there is some particular Windows edition or graphics hardware model or driver version that is affected?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case on Windows 10 still, but the absolute limit on older Windows was 16384 pixels.